# How to add timeout before stoping windows service that is hosted by topshelf

Tags: windows-services, topshelf

I have many windows services that I have installed using Top-Shelf.

I wondered if there is a way to set a timeout when stopping the service to enable on-going process that the service is currently handling to finish before the service actually closes?
I want to wait X seconds before I terminate the Top-Shelf.

This is my console which I have installed as a service:

```
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        return (int)HostFactory.Run(x =>
        {
            string serviceName = new ServiceNameResolverImpl().GetServiceName();
            x.SetServiceName(serviceName);
            x.SetDisplayName(serviceName);
            x.SetDescription(serviceName);

            x.UseAssemblyInfoForServiceInfo();
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.StartAutomaticallyDelayed();
            x.SetStartTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            x.Service<ServiceImpl>();
        });
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your service implementation, use the HostControl to *request* additional shutdown time (i'm presuming your service already implements `ServiceControl` as that's what `.Service<T>` expects) - note that the Service Control Manager may or may not grant the request:

```
public class ServiceImpl : ServiceControl
{
     public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
     {
          return true;
     }

     public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl) 
     {
          hostControl.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
          return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

similar to the start timeout

```
x.SetStopTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```